# data streaming has stopped working after update

Tags: 18.04, updates

This morning I received an update for Ubuntu 18.04 and since the install I have been unable to stream data using either Firefox or Chrome browsers.

Answer (score 0):

An additional restart seems to have fixed the issue.  I still don't know the cause but at least I can work now.